# Postgresql - moving data from loosely typed staging table to strongly typed final table - and catch errors

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, staging

I have a staging table that is loosely typed (all cols (except pk) of datatype text) and I want to move this data into a table that is correctly typed for the data e.g. numerics are numerics, dates are dates etc.

My initial approach is to create a cursor in pgsql and loop through the data inserting it into the final table with appropriate casts.

I will catch errors and use them to insert rows that fail into an errors table that I can look at and address later.

Is there a cleverer way of doing this?

Regards
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a PL/PgSQL function with a `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION WHEN ... END` block wrapping the operation(s) that might fail.

See [Postgres sql exception handling for batch insert](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31349970/398670) for an example, and caveats.

It'd be nice if PostgreSQL's cast functions could be called in a test mode, where they return a boolean result indicating success and discard the product, or even better return a tuple of `(result, successflag)`. That way you could do it all with plain SQL. Unfortunately they don't support that, so you've got to use an exception handling loop and subtransactions.